# sscanf to float using c

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

So I have a file that has multiple strings. I'm supposed to use `fgets` to read each line then use `sscanf` to break the string up and process them into my struct. Here's an example.

```
38L Lee, Victor; 2.8
```

The first is the id, second is name, and finally the gpa. When I try using sscanf to read the gpa, it's reading 0.0, rather than 2.8. Here's my code.

```
bool getstu (FILE* fpstu, STU* pstu)
{

//  Local Definitions
    int ioResult;
    char temp[100];
    char *ptr;
    char tempStr[50];

//  Statements
    fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fpstu);
    {
        ptr = temp;
        sscanf(ptr, "%3s", pstu->id);
        ptr += strlen(pstu->id) + 1;
        sscanf(ptr, "%[^;]", tempStr);

        pstu->name = aloName(tempStr);

        ptr += strlen(tempStr) + 2;
        sscanf(ptr, "%s", tempStr);
        sscanf(tempStr, "%3.1f", pstu->gpa);
    }

return ioResult == 1;
}// getstu
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `printf("tempStr is '%s'\n", tempStr);` to check what you're trying to convert?  What's the type of `pstu->gpa`?  `%f` converts a `float`, not a `double`.  The `3.1` isn't useful and would be better removed.

Comment: Never use `gets`.  Use `fgets` instead, because it accepts a size parameter which lets you avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: @TonyD : Yes, I've tried printing `tempStr` and it's printing `2.8`. `pstu->gpa` is type float.

Comment: @JohnZwinck : Thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo. I did use `fgets` in my program. Will fix the typo.

Comment: I confirmed on my machine - works without `3.1`, gets 0 with. I think the problem is that while a width specification - your "3" - is valid in a `scanf` format, a precision specification is not... that's only meaningful or allowed for output ala `printf`. For input, whatever precision the input has is consumed, irrespective of whether the type being read into can store it precisely or not.  See the manpage - http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sscanf(tempStr, "%3.1f", pstu->gpa);
```

should be

```
sscanf(tempStr, "%3.1f", &(pstu->gpa));
```

, I think.

Comment: +1 Oooh... I just took the address in my program without thinking - you're right - that's missing in the program. 3.1 doesn't work though - needs to be `%f` or `%3f`.

Comment: Ah, Okay, I see what went wrong there. Thanks for pointing this out. Much appreciated.